# export-ejb bug in glassfish 3.1?

Tags: ejb-3.0, osgi, glassfish-3

I noticed that OSGI doesn't publish OSGI services when EJB extends an abstract class and is exported as OSGI service (with export-ejb:all). 
(I use glassfish 3.1)

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

the manifest in EJB jar is:

```
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <Export-EJB>ALL</Export-EJB>
...
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
```

thanks

**Upd:** the problem is solved if EJB directly implements an interface (instead of extending a class that implements this interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also post this question in glassfish forum? Anyway, I replied there and the bottom line is it seems to me that super class interfaces are not considered business interfaces by default. See http://markmail.org/message/rirpdzw3r65gmng3 for detailed explanation.